# Generic Type extends Interface but gets an incompatible type error

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

I am new to Java -- coming from the PHP Python world. I am sure this is a simple question and that I'm missing something basic, but after a couple hours of searching and tinkering, I can't figure it out.

I have a `Path` class that keeps to points, an `In` and an `Out`:

```
public class Path<In extends PointInterface, Out extends PointInterface> {
    private In in;
    private Out out;

    public Path(In in, Out out) {
        this.in = in;
        this.out = out;
    }

    public In getIn() {
        return in;
    }

    public Out getOut() {
        return out;
    }
}
```

I have many implementations of `PointInterface`, for now, let's say `Queue` and `Endpoint`.

I want to be able to instantiate a `Path` object with any combination of those two `PointInterface` implementations.

That's all pretty easy.
`Path path = new Path<>(new Endpoint(), new Queue());`

*The Problem Is* that each of those implementations has its own handler for both In and Out. So, inside that `EndpointInHandler` I can be certain that `path.getIn()` will return an `Endpoint` (which implements `PointInterface`).

But, when I try `Endpoint in = path.getIn();` inside that method, I get an `Incompatible Types` error saying that it required `Endpoint` but found `PointInterface`.

`Endpoint` *implements* `PointInterface`.

I have tried:

- defining generics in the handlers like `InHandlerInterface<Endpoint>`
- not using the `extends` logic, but then I have the same problem with `Object`
- using Abstract classes instead of interfaces
- and a couple other things.

Can anyone help me understand what I'm missing? Much thanks :)

**Code Sample**

**Inside my Main method**:

```
Path path = new Path<>(new Endpoint(), new Queue());

InHandlerInterface handler = path.getIn().getInHandler(); // returns the EndpointInHandler
handler.handle(path);
```

**`Path`** detailed above.

**`PointInterface`**:

```
public interface PointInterface {
    InHandlerInterface getInHandler();
}
```

**`Endpoint`**:

```
public class Endpoint implements PointInterface {
    @Override
    public InHandlerInterface getInHandler() {
        return new EndpointInHandler();
    }

    public String specificToEndpoint() {
        return "Whatever";
    }
}
```

**`InHandlerInterface`**:

```
public interface InHandlerInterface {
    void handle(Path path);
}
```

`EndpointInHandler`:

```
public class EndpointInHandler implements InHandlerInterface {
    @Override
    public void handle(Path path) {
        Endpoint in = path.getIn(); // This is giving me the Incompatible types error

        String whatever = in.specificToEndpoint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question seems a bit confusing. Can you put a **reproducible** example code and point out where in the code you get the error? That way you will get solutions much faster.

Comment: @Codebender I can try, but it's several classes. Let me try to pair down to the bear minimum.

Comment: @Codebender is that helpful?

Comment: Even if you propagate all the generics to where they need to go, at the point you invoke `path.getIn()` all you know is that `getIn()` returns some unknown class that implements `PointInterface`.  There is no guarantee it is an `Endpoint`.  Generics are very useful, but they are not as powerful as they appear to someone coming from another language.  They are really only syntactic sugar at compile time to enforce type safety and eliminate some casts.  Generic type information does not propagate to runtime so what you are trying to accomplish cannot be done with generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `Path path = new Path<>(new Endpoint(), new Queue())`, you have effectively lost the type of the generics.

You need to write it as `Path<EndPoint, Queue> path = new Path<>(new Endpoint(), new Queue())` so that the compiler is aware what the actual types the generics are referring.

#### Update

Looking again, I realized that you need to put generics everywhere. It may look weird to see generics appearing everywhere, but this is the way to ensure compile-time type safety. Doing this, you would not need any explicit casts.

```
Path<Endpoint, Queue> path = new Path<>(new Endpoint(), new Queue());

InHandlerInterface<Endpoint> handler = path.getIn().getInHandler(); // returns the EndpointInHandler
handler.handle(path);
```

PointInterface:

```
public interface PointInterface<T extends PointInterface> {
    InHandlerInterface<T> getInHandler();
}
```

Endpoint:

```
public class Endpoint implements PointInterface<Endpoint> {
    @Override
    public InHandlerInterface<Endpoint> getInHandler() {
        return new EndpointInHandler<>();
    }

    public String specificToEndpoint() {
        return "Whatever";
    }
}
```

InHandlerInterface:

```
public interface InHandlerInterface<T extends PointInterface<T>> {
    void handle(Path<T, ?> path);
}
```

EndpointInHandler:

```
public class EndpointInHandler implements InHandlerInterface<Endpoint> {
    @Override
    public void handle(Path<Endpoint, ?> path) {
        Endpoint in = path.getIn(); // This is naturally type safe, and compiler won't complain

        String whatever = in.specificToEndpoint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Both of those solutions worked. One correction on the update: I had to add `<T extends PointInterface>` to `public class EndpointInHandler<T extends PointInterface>`, even though `T` is never used. Otherwise, it threw an error that I was using a diamond operator on a non-generic type.

Comment: you probably want to write the definition in the interface as `<T extends PointInterface<T>>` (the `<T>` at the end has been added)

Comment: @Lino Good point. That's the problem of answering without using IDE.